# Does "git diff branch1 branch2" represent the "absolute difference" between branches?

Tags: git

Git's algorithms can be confusing to understand and I want to make sure I know what this one does. Does it show the exact differences in files of the repository as it would be constructed at the `HEAD` of each branch? In other words, let's say I run

`git diff branch1 branch2`

and the only thing it shows is that Line 56 of Foo.cs is

```
+ var x = bar;
- var y = bar;
```

Am I correct that it implies the "snapshot" of the repository at the `HEAD` of `branch1` and `branch2` is the exact same other than those 2 lines? Or does the `diff` algorithm do something fancy with the nearest common commit such that I could see a difference that isn't really a difference?

Comment: Yes, your thinking seems to be correct.

Comment: You're right on in terms of what you are seeing, but your terminology (or at least syntax) doesn't quite match Git's: the word `HEAD` in all caps, or `@`, is a special name referring to the *current* branch, while the word `head` in lowercase (and generally rendered in ordinary font :-) ) refers to a "branch head" or "tip commit of a branch". A branch *name*, like `branch1`, is shorthand for the Git *reference* `refs/heads/branch1`, which contains the hash ID of the tip commit of the branch. If you `git checkout branch1` and make a *new* commit, Git handles that by [continued next comment]

Comment: ... Git handles that by writing the new commit to the repository, obtaining a new hash ID in the process, and then stuffing that new hash ID into the `refs/heads/branch1` entry, so that the name `branch1` now refers to that new commit. The commit's *parent* hash ID is whatever commit was the tip, before you made the new commit. This is how branches grow, in Git.

Answer (score 1):

When you see

```
+ var x = bar;
- var y = bar;
```

This means that `branch1` contains the first line and `branch2` contains the second line. All such differences between `branch1` and `branch2` will be shown, no more and no less. If any lines are not shown, then you can safely assume that they are identically the same.